# urllib2.urlopen a local file, cross platform

Tags: python, cross-platform, urllib2

I'm trying to open a local file using `urllib2` and have the following code:

```
r = urllib2.urlopen('file://' + some_path)
```

While this works on Unix, it does not work on Windows because of the `//`. What is the most pythonic way to have this work cross-platform?

Comment: If you use `file:///` (with three backslashes) your code will work. But some_path has to be in the form `c:/path/` with slashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`urllib.pathname2url`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.pathname2url):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> 'file:' + urllib.pathname2url(r'c:\path\to\something')
'file:///C:/path/to/something'
```

Answer (score 0):

This function's location has changed in Python 3. It is now urllib.request.pathname2url.